# To set off option that PhpStorm 2020.3.1 shows some hints hovering htmk tag

Tags: phpstorm

Using PhpStorm 2020.3.1 I see some hints when I really do not need them.
Say in cases when I hover mouse over “<div” tag.
If it possible to show this hint only on some action, say context menu some menu item selected?

Thanks!

Comment: what hints are meant? Please share a screenshot. also, does disabling **Show quick documentation on mouse move** in **Settings | Editor | Code Editing** help?

Comment: Thanks! that seems valid option. If there is a way to see this documentation by some sction(hot key, menu item) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try disabling **Show quick documentation on mouse move** in **Settings | Editor | Code Editing**.

Quick documentation can be viewed via **View | Quick documentation**; see what shortcut is assigned to this action (usually it's `Ctrl+Q` on Windows, `F1` on Mac OSX)